# Slave APCUPSD issuing killpower

Tags: apcupsd

I am using an APC BackUPS Pro to run two machines. One is critical and is connected directly to the UPS as the master and the other machine is not so important and is connected via the NIS as a slave.

As I understand it, if a machine is shutdown by APCUPSD it issues the killpower command to the UPS just before shutting down so that the UPS kills the power to connected deviced when it regains mains power to prompt the connected deviced to start up.

However it seems like all APCUPSD clients issue this command rather than just the master. Is this the correct behaviour?

I have the slave turning off 2 minutes after power loss but would like the master to continue running until 10% battery remains.